# "uninitialized constant Encoding" on each machine after installing ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created one website and started webricks server but the error is there.

```
D:\PROJECTS\RubyOnRail\webapp\Welcome>ruby script\server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2010-01-31 21:19:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-01-31 21:19:34] INFO  ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24) [i386-mswin32]
[2010-01-31 21:19:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6576 port=3000
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Sun Jan 31 21:19:38 +0530 2010
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  uninitialized constant Encoding
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-0.0.6/lib/sqlite3/encoding.rb:9:in `f
ind'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-0.0.6/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:69:in `
initialize'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `new'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `sqlite3_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/query_ca
che.rb:9:in `cache'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/query_ca
che.rb:28:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `
call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/params
_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/sessio
n/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/failsa
fe.rb:26:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchroniz
e'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/dispat
cher.rb:114:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/reload
er.rb:34:in `run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/dispat
cher.rb:108:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `c
all'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:i
n `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `
call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:50:in
`service'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in
`run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_origina
l_require'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Sun Jan 31 21:19:39 +0530 2010
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  uninitialized constant Encoding
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-0.0.6/lib/sqlite3/encoding.rb:9:in `f
ind'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-0.0.6/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:69:in `
initialize'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `new'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `sqlite3_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/query_ca
che.rb:9:in `cache'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/query_ca
che.rb:28:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `
call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/params
_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/sessio
n/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/failsa
fe.rb:26:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchroniz
e'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/dispat
cher.rb:114:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/reload
er.rb:34:in `run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/dispat
cher.rb:108:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `c
all'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:i
n `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `
call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:50:in
`service'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in
`run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_origina
l_require'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to be a smart mouth and say the problem is that you're running rails on a windows machine, but I used to be a microsoft man myself :)

There's an unrecognized constant Encoding, and it looks like it's part of the sqlite package.  Per the advice on this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797199/uninitialized-constant-encoding-with-sqlite3-ruby-on-windows), you need to uninstall sqlite3 and install sqlite3-ruby:

```
gem uninstall sqlite3
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```